# How do I get google maps Scale Control to default to imperial (miles)?

Tags: google-maps

Here is my map initialization

```
var userLatLong = new google.maps.LatLng(userLat,userLong),
            markers,
            userMapOptions = {
                zoom: 11,
                center: userLatLong,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                streetViewControl: false,
                zoomControlOptions: {
                    style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE,
                },
                scaleControl: true,
                panControl: true
            },
        userMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), userMapOptions);
```

I have tried adding "DirectionsUnitSystem: google.maps.DirectionsUnitSystem.IMPERIAL" but that doesn't help at all. userLat is 37.61 and userLong is -77.3 which is in Virginia.

From what I have been reading it looks like the scale value is supposed to start out as whatever country of origin you have selected.

I know clicking on the scale changes the scale units but I don't want the user having to click on the scale for it to change. I even tried a hack of trying to find the DOM object for the scale and sending a 'click' event by adding a listener of type 'idle' but when I hit a breakpoint within the listener the scale isn't drawn yet so it can't be accessed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I change the scale displayed in Google Maps API v3 to imperial (miles) units](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18067797/how-do-i-change-the-scale-displayed-in-google-maps-api-v3-to-imperial-miles-un)

Comment: A little hack posted on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18067797/how-do-i-change-the-scale-displayed-in-google-maps-api-v3-to-imperial-miles-un/21460426?iemail=1&noredirect=1#21460426 works for this.