# How do I tell map scale to show ft/miles instead of meters

Tags: google-maps-api-3

The Google API map scale used to always show both meters and imperial units (ft or miles).

Now when a map opens the scale is always only in meters.  If you click the actual scale image, you can toggle it to imperial units.  Not exactly intuitive and certainly a nuisance.

Anyone know how to tell the API to display a scale with types of units?  My server log shows users hitting my app from around the world.

BTW, setting google.maps.visualRefresh = false; 
does nothing.  The scale is now always part of the stuff in the lower right corner.

Edit: I just noticed that https://maps.google.com/ displays a nice scale with both mi and km.

Edit: No, not a duplicate.  My users in the USA want the scale to show mi and ft.  My users in other counties mostly want the scale to show m and km.  Since plain old Google maps shows both types of units on the scale, I am hoping there is a way to display a scale with the API that has both types of units.  Meanwhile, at least I can change the default to imperial via the hack in the other thread.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I change the scale displayed in Google Maps API v3 to imperial (miles) units](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18067797/how-do-i-change-the-scale-displayed-in-google-maps-api-v3-to-imperial-miles-un)